# GNAT - GVD: not in executable format: File format not recognized

Tags: file-format, ada, executable-format

I'm on an XP Virtual Machine running the GNU Visual Debugger 1.2.6, trying to open an Ada file (.adb), but keep getting the following error:

> not in executable format: File format
>   not recognized

I should also mention that I've installed both the Ada compiler kit and win32 tools for GNAT 3.14p.

I've since tried opening other .adb files from the GVD and even .c files, but all with the same happy response above.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: For now, I'm just bypassing the problem by using the gcc compiler, but I remain curious about the cause behind this error.

Comment: You are using an *ancient* version of GNAT--and GVD is long since deprecated. If at all possible you ought to move to GNAT GPL 2010 (http://libre.adacore.com/libre). Other than that, I'm guessing GVD's "Open..." is expecting an executable to open and debug, not a source file. But seriously, upgrade!

Comment: Should add that with GNAT GPL, you've got the debugger fully integrated into the GPS IDE.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. Fully integrated is nice. Few moving parts. Will explore more. This is what what was recommended by the professor for a class, so I was trying to model as close as possible the conditions by which the project would be evaluated!

Comment: *Recommended by the professor???* Oh Lord. Even the last unencumbered free version of GNAT was *3.15p*. Go get GNAT GPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GVD does not take a source file as an argument, it takes an executable program.  Skipping a lot of if this and if that, to debug foo.adb you probably want to pass foo.exe to the debugger.

But this is Ada, and you shouldn't be here. ;-)  If you got your source program to compile and produce an executable, you very seldom need to run the debugger.  I can remember the last time I used the debugger with GNAT, and why.  (A bug in Solaris, the workaround was change a constant to a variable--Solaris was overwriting the value passed in instead of using a temp.)  But that was what?  Five years ago?

It is much easier to put in some debugging code (see pragma Debug in the GNAT documentation), then run the program with the debug flag if necessary.

Oh, most important.  You may need to look in C:\GNAT\2010\share\doc\ to find all the documentation that came with GNAT.  Read it. Or at least figure out how to search it for what you need. ;-)

Comment: Excellent. I was starting to suspect it didn't want source at all. I'll check into the pragma Debug as well. I ended up running to the command line to compile anyway.

Comment: lol. Nice thought, but I can vouch that a good debugger is quite handy, even with Ada code. You don't have to live your life in the debugger, like you do with C code, but it can be very helpful.